# Add fields to User model in Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm a bit of a newbie at Rails and feel I'm missing a trick here.  I'm trying to add a phone_number field to my Devise-generated User model, but I'm having an issue with saving it.  I've done the `rails generate devise:views`, updated the edit.html.erb file to add in the :phone_number field, and created a migration to add the phone_number field to the model.  It's not saving to the model because (as I understand it) I can't update the controller to include the new fields.

Do I need to create an `app/controllers/users/registration_controller.rb` defined with `class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController` and then monkey patch the update method?  Or is there a more straightforward/elegant/easier way?

I realize there are a couple other questions related to this on the site, but one offers no useful answers, and the other simply details what I mention here.  Is there anything more to it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After you add the field to your database through a migration you will also need to add it to your list of accessible attributes in your User model.  Your attr_accessible list should look something like the following depending on what devise modules you are using.

```
attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :phone_number
```

Comment: In Rails 4, remember to use strong parameters instead. e.g. `params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :phone_number)`